# how i set title toolbar many times?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

```
private void setTitleText(String Title) {
    toolbar =  getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);        
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Title);
}
```

this function works only for the first call

Comment: `toolbar.setTitle("title");` ? what do you mean by many times ?

Comment: @ADM like this    public void onPageSelected(int position) {



                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        

                        setTitleText("page1");



                        break;
                    case 1:

                 

                        setTitleText("page2"); default : ..... }}

Answer (score 0):

Better you get the toolbar and put in a variable in the oncreate method on your activity, then do the method just setting up the value still in the activity.

```
onCreate(){
   toolbar = getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   toolbar.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

then in the method:

```
public void setTitle(String title){
   toolbar.setTitle(title);
}
```

you can acess from others fragments of that activity too.

Comment: The problem in your method is that you are creating a new toolbar to the activity each time. so ir overwrites the old one or not works.

Comment: i put it in onCreate() but the value  of the title still the first value

Comment: But you did this method in the fragment, right? if yes, you must to do it on the activity and make it public and just call it in the fragment.